Help simplifying the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ if $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = 0$
Starting from:
$$
\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}
\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}
\Var(X+Y) = \Var(X) + \Var(Y) + 2\Cov(X,Y) 
$$
we have that
$$
\Cov(X,Y) = -\frac{1}{2} \bigl( \Var(X) + \Var(Y) \bigr)
$$
with the correlation being
$$
\rho_{XY}^{\strut} = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\Var(X) + \Var(Y)}{\sqrt{\Var(X)\Var(Y)}}
$$
I've tried to further simplify it, but ended up with uninformative bounds.

There are not a lot of distributions with $0$ variance

Non-formally:  If the variance of the sum is zero, it means that the sum is a constant (deterministic) number C. And this means that Y=C-X, from which it follows that the correlation is -1, due to the perfect linear relation.

@Lior. Well,  almost surely constant.  Meaning,  equal to its mean except possibly on a set of probability $0$.

You should remember the definition of the variance: $Var(X) = E\left(X - \overline X\right)^2$. As it is the expected value of a positive variable, it can only be $0$ if the variable is constant except on a set having a null measure.

@lulu right, hence the "non-formally"

@SergeBallesta: I've tried using $Var(X + Y) = 0 -> E(X+Y) = c$ but the only way I find to get to $\rho_{xy} = -1$ is when using $Var(Y) = Var(C - X) = Var(X)$, but it gives me the "non-formal" vibes.

@boccaff: You misinterpreted what I wrote. If $X$ and $Y$ have their values in an universe $U$, what I wrote means $Var(X + Y) = 0 \implies \exists c\in U/p(X+Y!=c)=0$. In English it means that $X+Y$ is constant except on a set having a null probability.

@boccaff It does not just imply the triviality that $\mathsf E(X+Y)$ equals some constant (as that is true by definition).  Rather it implies that $\boldsymbol {X+Y}$ almost surely equals that constant.   That implies that $\mathsf{Var}(Y)=\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(X+Y)-X)=\mathsf E(X)$

@GrahamKemp I think you meant to write $$\mathsf{Var}(Y)=\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(X+Y)-X)=\mathsf{Var}(X)$$ (so $\rho_{XY}=-1$).

Yes, indeed I did.
